# Get list of movies directed by director- IMDbPY

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

I use the below code to get the director name of a particular movie. How can I get a list of all movies directed by the director.
In this case I chose Interstellar and the Director I get will be Christopher Nolan. So how can I list all the movies directed by him?

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()

movie = ia.get_movie('0816692')
print "Name of the movie: ", movie
for i in movie['director']:
    print "Director: ", i
    for k in ia.search_person(str(i))[:1]:
        print k.personID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `get_person` with the director's id as argument and find the names of the movies he directed by accessing the person object with the key `director movie`:

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()

movie = ia.get_movie('0816692')
print "Name of the movie: ", movie
for i in movie['director']:
    print "Director: ", i
    for k in ia.search_person(str(i))[:1]:
        director = ia.get_person(k.personID)
        print "Movies directed by %s" % director
        print "-------------------------------"
        for movie_name in director['director movie']:
            print movie_name
```

**Update**

---

I played a little bit with the library and found an even simpler approach to your problem without the nested for loops:

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()

movie = ia.get_movie('0816692')
print "Name of the movie: ", movie
for i in movie['director']:
    print "Director: ", i
    director = ia.search_person(i["name"])[0]
    ia.update(director)
    print "Movies directed by %s:" % director
    for movie_name in director["director movie"]:
        print movie_name
```

Comment: k.key2infoset could be useful for identifying what the available keys in the dictionary are. Also dir() was helpful in figuring out what the API exposes (at least for me)

Answer (score 0):

we are in 2022 and I tried your code @halex but it doesn't work anymore. That is why I find a new way:

```
def get_director_id(mv_id):

ia = imdb.IMDb()

movie= ia.get_movie(mv_id)
dict_directors={}
directors= movie['director']

for dir in directors:
    dict_directors[dir]= dir.personID

return(dict_directors)
    





def get_director_movie(nb, dir_id):

ia = imdb.IMDb()

dict_mv={}
dir_info= ia.get_person_filmography(dir_id)
tmp= dir_info['data']['filmography']['director']
for i in range(len(tmp)-1, len(tmp)-nb-1, -1):
    title= str(dir_info['data']['filmography']['director'][i])
    print(title)
    id= dir_info['data']['filmography']['director'][i].movieID
    print(id)
    dict_mv[title]= id
return(dict_mv)

dict= get_director_movie(3, "0905154")
titles= list(dict.keys())
id= list(dict.values())
```